# retrieve a specific data from a table after a symbol in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table DATA
----------------------------
Name   
ABC:000
DEF:0
ABD:000
FFF:00
GGG:000
```

I need only those names which contains only 3 characters post the semicolon.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that the field is stored as a `char()` and varying, then use `trim()`:

```
where trim(name) like '%:___'
```

Comment: .. and that spaces should be ignored (which is not stated in the OP's question). If spaces should indeed be ignored, a similar trimming would be necessary in the VARCHAR2 case, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  table_name ( name ) as (
  select 'ABC:000' from dual union all
  select 'DEF:0'   from dual union all
  select 'ABD:000' from dual union all
  select 'FFF:00'  from dual union all
  select 'GGG:000' from dual
  )
-- End of SIMULATED inputs (not part of the SQL query).
-- Solution begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select name
from   table_name
where  name like '%:___'
;

NAME
-------
ABC:000
ABD:000
GGG:000
```

Explanation: `like` is a comparison operator for strings. `%` stands for any sequence of characters, of any length (including of length zero). `:` stands for itself. Underscore stands for exactly one character - ANY character. The comparison string is one `%` sign, one `:` semicolon, and **three** underscores.

Comment: I want only those names which exactly has 3 characters post the colon

Comment: @user2814847 - Are you suggesting that this solution does something else?

Comment: @user2814847 : Just thanks and smileys are not sufficient here in SO.You should upvote and mark as best answer if you found it useful.